# Removing Focus In Edit Text

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-edittext

I am trying to have an edit text that will not receive focus (that brings out the softkeyboard and the blinking cursor) while still receiving touch input.

Apparently, for now, if I were to try using the methods like setFocusable(false) and setFocusableInTouchMode(false) or setEnabled(false) it will not receive any touch input.

How can I go about this?

UPDATE:

```
editText = (EditText) = layout.findViewById(R.id.edittext);
    editText.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return true;
        } 
  });
```

Comment: looks interesting, I would be interested to know how you did this if you managed to pull this off. I will try and dig around to see if anything I can find out.

Comment: @bandaa25 yeah, i can't seem to figure that out after quite some debugging still. anyway, something extra that may help is that when I try changing the edit text to something else like a textview or even image view, with all those focusable, enabled, focusableintouchmodeto false, it will still work.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you setOnTouchListener() and ovverride onTouch() to return true, it should work.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have updated the question. am I doing it right? because it is still not working.

Comment: it is still not receiving any touch input.

Comment: That is strange as I used the same method and I see debugger coming to {return true;} statement..... Can you tell me what exactly are you trying to achieve with touch event ...?

Comment: I am trying to allow the user to drag and move the item according to the position of his finger. in my activity there's a layout which will handle all my these touch events.

Comment: apparently when I try with something else that doesn't deals with all these focus stuff, it will work fine.

Comment: Sorry I was out for few days... Were you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove by calling ontouch method on any view in your layout

```
val eventDown = MotionEvent.obtain(0, 20, MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, 0f, 0f, 0)
frameLayView.onTouchEvent(eventDown)
val eventUp = MotionEvent.obtain(0, 20, MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, 0f, 0f, 0)
frameLayView.onTouchEvent(eventUp)
```